# JavaScript return promise from function

Tags: javascript, function, promise, return

I'm trying to return data from a called function that has a promise in it. How do I get the data into the variable?

```
var job = fetchJob(data[k].employer);
```

```
function fetchJob(name) {
        var test = 'null'
        fetch(`https://${ GetParentResourceName() }/jsfour-computer:policeFetchJob`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                type: 'policeFetchJob',
                data: {
                    '@name': name,
                }
            })
        })
        .then( response => response.json() )
        .then( data => {

            if ( data != 'false' && data.length > 0 ) {
                return data
        })
        return null;
    };
```

Comment: you can't like that ... firstly, you need to return the Promise returned by fetch (you currently return undefined since there's no return from fetchJob), then to access the data you need to use .then where you call `fetchJob`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the promise value with async/await or with Promises, bellow I do an example with this two techniques:

```js
function fetchJob(name) {
  return fetch(`https://${GetParentResourceName()}/jsfour-computer:policeFetchJob`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      type: "policeFetchJob",
      data: {
        "@name": name,
      },
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      if (data != "false" && data.length > 0) {
        return data;
      }
    });
}



async function getResponseWithAsyncAwait() {
  const job = await fetchJob(data[k].employer);
}

function getResponseWithPromises() {
  fetchJob(data[k].employer).then((data) => {
    const job = data;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Oscar! Async worked!

```
async function getResponseWithAsyncAwait() {
  const job = await fetchJob(data[k].employer);
}
```